# preg_replace in for loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, preg-replace

I want to insert   symbol after some conjunctions. $cont variable has some text. My code:

```
$conjs = array ('i', 'a', 'w'); 
$size = sizeof($conjs);
$replacm = ' $1&nbsp;';

for ($i=0; $i < $size; $i++){
    $pattern = '/\s(' . $conjs[$i] . ')(\s)/';
    $replaced = preg_replace($pattern, $replacm, $cont);
}

print $replaced;
```

This returns $cont text changed only with last array element ("w"). What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `preg_replace()` takes an array as argument, so you can just do: `$patterns = array_map(function($v){return "/\s(" . $v . ")(\s)/";}, $conjs); echo $replaced = preg_replace($patterns, "$1&nbsp;", $cont);`

Comment: [Don't use `sizeof()` to get the array length](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.sizeof.php#85892).

Comment: But what is `$cont` over here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try change your `for` to:

```
for ($i=0; $i < $size; $i++){
    $pattern = '/\s(' . $conjs[$i] . ')(\s)/';
    $cont= preg_replace($pattern, $replacm, $cont);
}
```

Comment: Your are declaring `$replaced` each time in your loop, so the `$replaced` is being... replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Working example

```
$cont = 'any text word';
$conjs = array ('i', 'a', 'w'); 
$size = sizeof($conjs);
$replacm = '$';

for ($i=0; $i < $size; $i++){
    $pattern = '/' . $conjs[$i] . '/';    
    $cont= preg_replace($pattern, $replacm, $cont);
}

print $cont;
```

Answer (score 0):

This method already exists in [T-Regx tool](https://t-regx.com) and it's called `chainedReplac()`.

```
Pattern::compose(['\si(\s)', '\sa(\s)', '\sw(\s)'])->chainedReplace($cont)->with("'$1&nbsp;");
```

Not to mention you could just do

```
Pattern::of('\s[iaw](\s)')->replace($cont)->all()->with('$1&nbsp;');
```